# Update column value with " using Apache NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I tried to update column value using `UpdateRecord`  processor.

```
id,name,string_column
1,sachith,test-1
2,nalaka,test-2
```

I want to update this as `1,sachith,"test-1"`

I use literal replace and
`/string_column : ${field.value:replaceAll(${filed.value},'\"${filed.value}\"')}`

But output looks like `1,sachith,"""test-1"""`

Edit
CSVReader :

```
Schema Access Strategy : Using String fields from headers
CSV Parser  : Apache Common CSV
Character set : UTF-8
```

CSVRecordSetWriter :

```
Schema Write Strategy  : Do not write schema
Schema access strategy : Inherit record schema
```

What did I miss here?

Comment: Please check how you have configured Record Reader/Writer!

Comment: @VikramsinhShinde updated with reader and writer details.

Comment: For `CSVRecordSetWriter`, try setting `Quote Mode` = `Do Not Quote Values`

Comment: @VikramsinhShinde Yes, it solved the problem, could you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set `Quote Mode` property value to `Do Not Quote Values` for `CSVRecordSetWriter` controller service.